# Assigning an IP address

Tags: cisco, ip, cisco-commands, ip-address

on a switch or router interfaces,why can't I assign an IP address with 32 bit subnet mask (255.255.255.255)?and should be (255.255.255.0)
kindly enlighten me on that.

[image]

Comment: I suspect this is very dependent on router model and software version.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An IP address is a parameter to make a device to **get into** a network.

The netmask defines the **size** of the network, for example:

- /24 (255.255.255.0)  has 256 addresses in the network.
- /30 (255.255.255.252) has 4 addreses in the network.

/32 (255.255.255.255) has 1 adddress in the network. So the device will be **isolated** and not in a network.

If you could be able to assign that address, how can it be acccesed if it is alone?

There is an exception to that and it is when you create a loopback interface that doesn't need to be accesible from outside.

Comment: Additionally, modern network devices should also support /31 subnets for point-to-point links. These have the same function as /30 but don't waste half the subnet.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** assign a /32 address to certain interfaces - specifically loopback addresses.  Loopbacks are always up and act as a logical destination on a given IP host.

Non loopback interfaces are generally either broadcast or point-to-point (a few other options exist, but aren't common).  These interfaces are specifically set up to get traffic from one point to another and, as such, a subnet with only one host possible doesn't make sense.